# combine two regular expressions into one

Tags: javascript, regex

there I apply two regular expression to javascript string:

```
url.replace(/(^https?\:\/\/)?(www\.)?/i, '').replace(/\/$/, '')
```

how can I combine them into one `replace` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the replacement is the same, you can use alternation to match/replace "this" or "that":

```js
 let url = 'http://www.example.com/';
 console.log(url.replace(/^(?:https?\:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?|\/$/gi, ''));
```

Comment: You don't need the outermost prenthesised sub-expressions (e.g. `(\/$)` can just be `\/$`)

Comment: @Scoots I wasn't sure, I didn't test my regex at all. When in doubt I use parentheses...

Comment: sorry but doesn't work.. this should delete last slash from url but it doesn't

Comment: @O.Shekriladze that's because it's missing the trailing `g` flag - without that flag, JS regex relace will only replace a single instance. I'm going to hazard a guess you're testing both sides in a single test, so it's matching the https://www. first, and then just stopping

Comment: Thanks @Scoots I missed that in my answer

Comment: @O.Shekriladze I have edited in an update for Monkey's answer.